# Foreach loop through the results of query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a query that returns a list of userid based on the query below

```
SELECT DISTINCT [AUTHORIZATION_NAME] 
INTO #TEMP 
FROM [saving].[SAV_AUTHORIZATION] WHERE [ACTIVE_FLAG] = 1 AND [SAV_AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_ID] = 4
```

Now, for each user in `#TEMP` I want to insert a new row into another table. How can I do that?

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [saving].[SAV_INITIATIVES_APPROVAL]
    (
        [SAV_INITIATIVES_ID],
        [APPROVAL_DATE_SUBMITTED],
        [APPROVAL_BY_NM],
        [APPROVAL_BY_DT],
        [LAST_UPDATE_DATE],
        [LAST_UPDATE_USER],
        [ACTIVE_FLAG]
    )
    VALUES (
        @ID,
        GETDATE(),
        @APPROVER_NM, //// here i want foreach username
        NULL,
        GETDATE(),
        @LAST_UPDATE_USER,
        1
    )
END
```

Comment: Just using the normal `INSERT INTO MyTable (Cols) SELECT cols {query to get values}` which you can [read in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). You don't even need a temp table.

Comment: You almost never need a loop in a relational database, they are built to use set based operations i.e. handle a set of data at a time.

Comment: lets say i have 3 usernames in temp table and now i want to insert 3 rows in SAV_INITIATIVES_APPROVAL (for each user one row). how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an insert-select statement, where you query any values that don't come from the original table:

```sql
INSERT INTO [saving].[SAV_INITIATIVES_APPROVAL]
(
    [SAV_INITIATIVES_ID],
    [APPROVAL_DATE_SUBMITTED],
    [APPROVAL_BY_NM],
    [APPROVAL_BY_DT],
    [LAST_UPDATE_DATE],
    [LAST_UPDATE_USER],
    [ACTIVE_FLAG]
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT @ID,
    GETDATE(),
    [AUTHORIZATION_NAME], 
    NULL,
    GETDATE(),
    @LAST_UPDATE_USER,
    1
FROM 
    [saving].[SAV_AUTHORIZATION] 
WHERE
    [ACTIVE_FLAG] = 1 AND [SAV_AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_ID] = 4
```